# how to run a groovy script with maven invoker plugin

Tags: maven, maven-invoker-plugin

I have a groovy script in `src/it/first/ver.groovy`

If I use the `exec-maven-plugin` I can run it, but if I use the `maven-invoker-plugin` I cannot. I would prefer to use the invoker...

Example of config using `exec-maven-plugin` :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>src/it/first/ver.groovy</executable>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Example of config using `maven-invoker-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <projectsDirectory>src/it/first</projectsDirectory>
        <postBuildHookScript>ver.groovy</postBuildHookScript>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and the output is

`[INFO] --- maven-invoker-plugin:3.1.0:run (integration-test) @ demo ---
[INFO] No projects were selected for execution.`

Comment: The groovy script is usually named by a convention which is `verify.groovy`...so no need to st postBuildHookScripts...Furthermore the projectsDirectory is usually set to `src/it`...and no the exec-maven-plugin is not needed...

Comment: Even if I use the conventions I don't think it's going to work. The question is that I don't understand how this plugin works... The example I gave with the exec-plugin works, but I would like to use the invoker-plugin instead.

Comment: For other people, that stumble over this: "No projects were selected for execution" -> maven invoker expects Maven projects in the `projectsDirectory`, so this should probably be `src/it/` (as already mentioned) with a project `first` containing a `pom.xml` and the `ver.groovy` script. So one set of hook scripts per maven project that should be tested.